# jquery ui contextmenu won't attach to dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, contextmenu

I'm using jquery ui contextmenus ... easy to use ... except when I try to attach them to a dialog. Then nothing happens.

What follows is a small program to illustrate the problem. I have a button which pops up a jquery ui dialog and the dialog contains a table. I am delegating the context menu to a class.  But when I right click, all I get is the system menu.

Any help gratefully received!

Cheers
Geoff

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>AJP Policy Database</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/humanity/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui-contextmenu.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <button id="b1">Dialog</button>
 <div id="d1" class="hasmenu"></div>
 <div id="t1">
 <table>
 <thead>
 <th>HHHH</th>
 <th>IIII</th>
 <th>jjj</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr> <td>bbb</td> <td>ccc</td> <td>ddd</td> </tr>
 <tr> <td>bbb</td> <td>ccc</td> <td>ddd</td> </tr>
 <tr> <td>bbb</td> <td>ccc</td> <td>ddd</td> </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
</body>
<script>
$( function() {
 $("#b1").click(function() { showDialog(); });
});
function showDialog() {
 var htmls=`<table id="dialogtable">
 <thead>
 <th>HHHH</th>
 <th>IIII</th>
 <th>jjj</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr> <td>bbb</td> <td>ccc</td> <td>ddd</td> </tr>
 <tr> <td>bbb</td> <td>ccc</td> <td>ddd</td> </tr>
 <tr> <td>bbb</td> <td>ccc</td> <td>ddd</td> </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 `;
 $("#d1").dialog({title: "Comments", autoOpen: false}); 
 $("#d1").dialog("open").html(htmls);
 setContextMenu();
}
function setContextMenu() {
 $("#d1").contextmenu({
  delegate: ".hasmenu",
  menu: [
     {title: "T1", cmd: "t1"},
     {title: "T2", cmd: "t1"}
     ],
  select: function(event, ui) {
   alert(ui.cmd);
  }
 });
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Am finding in my testing that something is catching the right-click or contextmenu event in the dialog.

Fiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/eahgrb5j/

```js
$(function() {

  function initContextMenu(tObj) {
    tObj.contextmenu({
      delegate: ".hasmenu",
      menu: [{
        title: "Edit",
        cmd: "edit"
      }, {
        title: "Delete",
        cmd: "delete"
      }],
      select: function(event, ui) {
        alert(ui.cmd);
      }
    });
  }

  function showDiag(dObj, tStr, cHtm) {
    if (tStr == undefined) {
      tStr = "Comment"
    }
    if (cHtm == undefined) {
      cHtm = '<p>Right-Click an item below</p><table id="dialogtable"><thead><th class="hasmenu">HHHH</th><th class="hasmenu">IIII</th><th class="hasmenu">jjj</th></thead><tbody><tr><td class="hasmenu">bbb</td><td class="hasmenu">ccc</td><td class="hasmenu">ddd</td></tr><tr><td class="hasmenu">bbb</td><td class="hasmenu">ccc</td><td class="hasmenu">ddd</td></tr><tr><td class="hasmenu">bbb</td><td class="hasmenu">ccc</td><td class="hasmenu">ddd</td></tr></tbody></table>';
    }
    dObj.html(cHtm);
    dObj.dialog({
      title: tStr,
      autoOpen: false
    });
    dObj.dialog("open");
    initContextMenu($("table", dObj));
  }

  $("#b1").click(function() {
    showDiag($("#d1"), "Special Comment");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/humanity/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.ui-contextmenu/1.18.1/jquery.ui-contextmenu.min.js"></script>

<button id="b1">Dialog</button>
<div id="d1"></div>
<div id="t1">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>HHHH</th>
      <th>IIII</th>
      <th>jjj</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

You can see that the Table area suppresses the right-click. So something is happening, but I can't identify what at this time. Look at it more later.

Comment: I spent about 6 hours looking at it! But my web programming experience is slim and I didn't find a solution ... so switched to a different plugin ... contextMenu ... the interface is a little different, but it seems solid.  Many thanks for looking at at and at least confirming that I hadn't made some super simple mistake!